# Highlight and extract specific rows in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a large sheet with some thousands of rows. I would like to highlight and remove specific rows.

These row #'s are present on a separate CSV file.

If possible, I would like to to reference this CSV file and automatically remove the row #'s that are stated.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You asked this [already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37665649/extract-specific-rows-in-excel-based-on-csv) XD Edit: lol 2 days later and still didn't try anything XD

Comment: @findwindow you really keep your eye out for serial askers don't you?

Comment: @gtwebb nope. Just good memory ~_^ Edit: the other guy earlier was because I made a poor comment to an answer that was posted so that stuck with me.

Comment: @findwindow is right. There is no need to post the same question over and over again. I'm voting to close it. Besides, I thought that the recommendations were pretty good on the last post (including a link to a working solution).

Comment: @gtwebb and the other guy wasn't asking the same thing. He was literally asking each step of his project.